# azure function c# http trigger blob output

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions-core-tools

Can someone describe me how I can configure a C# azure function which uses an HTTP input trigger and a blob storage output trigger?

Maybe also with an example code snippet and an example function.json. I don't get it to work locally with the azure functions core tools.

Comment: you are looking for function 2.x sample?

Comment: yes preferable. but if easier with 1x also possible

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a combined HTTP triggered function with a output blob binding:

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggeredFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest httpRequest,
    [Blob("blobcontainer", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudBlobContainer outputContainer,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    await outputContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    var requestBody = await new StreamReader(httpRequest.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    var blobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var cloudBlockBlob = outputContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    await cloudBlockBlob.UploadTextAsync(requestBody);

    return new OkObjectResult(blobName);
}
```

It uses the `CloudBlobContainer` output type to get a reference to the blob container which then enables you to use methods such as `.GetBlockBlobReference("blobPath")` to get a reference to a blob.

Once you have a reference to a blob, you can use different methods to upload:

- `cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync()`
- `cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync()`
- `cloudBlockBlob.UploadTextAsync()`
- `cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync()`

To get it running locally, you need set some things up. Notice in my example the attribute `[Blob("blobcontainer", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]`

- "blobcontainer" this can be whatever you want and will be the name of the container that will be created in your storage account by this line `outputContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();` (if it doesn't exist already).
- Connection = "StorageConnectionString" this can be a setting in your `local.settings.json` for the connection string of your storage account. When developing locally I would recommend setting this to `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` so that you can take advantage of the storage emulator. Then when you are ready to deploy onto Azure, you would create a setting in the function app containing the real connection string.

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",

    "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, do you know by any chance  to use CloudBlobContainer outputContainer in isolated model?

Answer (score 4):

to make an http function that saves to Blob Storage use this code:

```
 #r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log,TextWriter outputBlob)
{
   
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    outputBlob.WriteLine(requestBody);
 
    string result =  "{ 'result':  'ok' }";
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
      
    return new OkObjectResult(data);
}
```

You need to set the output binding:

[image]

You can then run a test posting content on the test window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest code to accomplish this task.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, out string outputBlob)
{
    outputBlob = "This is a Blob content";
    return new OkResult();
}
```

The input and output parameters are specified in the function.json file and are additionally presented graphically in the Integration tab.

function.json file content:

```
{"bindings":[{"authLevel": "ANONYMOUS",
    "name": "req",
    "type": "httpTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "methods": ["get","post"]
},{
    "name": "$return",
    "type": "http",
    "direction": "out"
},{
    "name": "outputBlob",
    "direction": "out",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "outcontainer/{rand-guid}",
    "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
}]}
```

Integration tab content:
[image]

local.settings.json file content

```
{"IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet" }}
```

The function can be extended by adding logging and reading data from the request.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, out string outputBlob, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    outputBlob = $"This Blob was created by HttpTrigger1 because at {DateTime.Now} request was sent to: {req.Host}";
    return new OkResult();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything you need is there in the Official docs page,

(i) **[`Http and WebHooks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---c-example)**

(ii)**[`Output binding blob storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output)**

**Http Trigger Sample code**

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

**Blob Storage Output binding**

```
[FunctionName("ResizeImage")]
public static void Run(
    [BlobTrigger("sample-images/{name}")] Stream image,
    [Blob("sample-images-sm/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageSmall,
    [Blob("sample-images-md/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageMedium)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. What I need is this combined. the problem is that I can not add to a variable like "out string myOutputBlob" to the run function containing and HttpTrigger.