# Azure function .net 5 Isolated blob output binding

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to create a Blob in the 'test ' container. In old version,i.e Azure function 3.1, I was using out parameter and UploadFromStreamAsync() . However, in new version , there is not parameter.

I am getting error message , ****Server not found Internal server error** 500**.

Can someone guide me ?

The code below

```
namespace FunctionBlobOut
{
  public static class Function1
  {

 [Function("BlobOut")]
 [BlobOutput("test")]
 public static async Task<MemoryStream>       
     Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,  "post")] HttpRequestData req,
     FunctionContext executionContext)
 {          
     try
     {
         using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
         {
             await req.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
             return ms;
         }
     }
     catch (System.Exception exp)
     {
         return null;
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: See this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743568/azure-function-c-sharp-http-trigger-blob-output

Comment: You gave me solution for Azure functions in .NET 3X  That was my old solution. Now, I am upgrading to .NET 5 (Azure function Isolated). So please read the question .

Answer (score 0):

Azure function .net 5 Isolated blob output binding

The output binding for a simple http function is similar to old class library. The return value of your method is the http response.
You can no longer specify binding attributes on the arguments of your function. this is done through return value of function method

```
 public static class MultiOutput
    {
        [Function("MultiOutput")]
        public static MyOutputType Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext context)
        {
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.WriteString("Success!");

            string myQueueOutput = "some output";

            return new MyOutputType()
            {
                Name = myQueueOutput,
                HttpResponse = response
            };
        }
    }

    public class MyOutputType
    {
        [QueueOutput("myQueue")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get; set; }
    }
```

For further information you can refer [Output Binding](https://dev.to/oscarvantol/multiple-output-bindings-in-azure-functions-isolated-process-model-46ag)

Comment: Can you please give a similar example for BlobOutput.  FYI , For the Queue , it works for me. I need to Blobs to be created.

Comment: Hey, do you know by any chance to use CloudBlobContainer outputContainer in isolated model?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.
I haven't tested this, but modified it based on some code I had lying around.

```
namespace FunctionBlobOut
{
  public static class Function1
  {
    [Function("BlobOut")]
    public static async Task<MyOutputType> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
      var result = new MyOutputType();

      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        await req.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
        result = new MyOutputType { Blob = ms.GetBuffer() };
      }

      result.HttpResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

      return result;
    }
  }

  public class MyOutputType
  {
    [BlobOutput("container/filename", Connection = "BlobStorage")]
    public byte[]? Blob { get; set; }

    public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Some things worth pointing out:

- In isolated mode you don't have the fancy bindings you otherwise have. That means that you need to use basic types like byte[] and string. Stream, Blob, BlobClient etc. won't work.
- Since you are receiving an HTTP request, you should return an HTTP response in addition to you blob.
- If, in some cases you don't want to produce a blob, simply set `MyOutputType.Blob` to `null`. The fact that this is nullable will avoid creating an empty blob. I'm not exactly sure what happens if you pass an empty byte[].

Personally, in this case, I would just return an HTTP response and deal with the blob using the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` library (BlobClient etc.), not using any form of output binding. I prefer having more power and flexibility than shorter code.